# How can I save an image in Python?

Tags: image, python-3.x, pygame

I've made a really basic drawing program in Python with Pygame. The program has a square window, in which you draw. How could I save the area inside the window as an image?

Comment: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.save

Answer (score 0):

As downshift commented, use [pygame.image.save](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.save)

```
win = pygame.display.set_mode(...)
# your stuff
pygame.image.save(win, "screenshot.jpg")
```